# Uniswap V3 Pools List

Tags: uniswap

My current understanding of Uniswap V3 the following code is required to get the address of a pool:

getPool(tokenA, tokenB, FEE)

My problem at this stage is I need to GUESS what the fee could be.  I see they are sometimes 0.05% and other times 0.3% or anything inbetween.

How can I get all the pools for tokenA and tokenB without specifying a fee ?

Comment: Checking [info.uniswap.org](https://info.uniswap.org/#/) and the [Uniswap v3 subgraph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph?id=0x9bde7bf4d5b13ef94373ced7c8ee0be59735a298-1&view=Overview).

Answer (score 1):

The only fee tiers possible in Uniswap v3 at the moment: 1%, 0.3%, 0.05% and 0.01%. (The first three were present by default, the fourth one was voted in through governance.) In the future, more might be added, but it's unlikely there will be many more.

In the code, the fee tiers are expressed in basis points (1/100 of percents) multiplied by 100:

- for 1% pools the fee tier is 10000
- for 0.3% pools the fee tier is 3000
- for 0.05% pools the fee tier is 500
- for 0.01% pools the fee tier is 100

Comment: There is also 0.01% fee tier now voted in through the governance https://gov.uniswap.org/t/introduce-stablecoin-liquidity-pools-with-0-01-fees-to-uniswap-v3-on-polygon-pos/15982

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I updated the answer, thanks for pointing it out